# Ordering in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

if i used OrderingFilter class from DRF filters, is it will use order_by function or what it use?

Example

```
from django_filters import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters


class InvoiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer

    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter)

    ordering_fields = ('created', 'modified',)
```

If yes then i have to use indexes for these fields if i use it in every filter in project ?!

Answer (score -1):

`ordering` is the default query parameter.

Try like this -

```
http://example.com/api/users?ordering=username
http://example.com/api/users?ordering=-username
```

But you can override this by setting the `ORDERING_PARAM` in the `settings.py`

See the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter).

Comment: i'm just want to know ordering in params like order_by('-created') or there any differ?